# Transforming Hermite Polynomial Recursion to a solution using std::stack

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, stack

Hermite polynomials are defined by the following formulas, where n>0 and x is a real number:
[image: Hermite formulas]

I have already defined a solution using recursion:

```
int hermitPolynomial(int n, int x){
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    if (n == 1){
        return x*2;
    }
    return 2*x*hermitPolynomial(n-1,x) + 2*(n-1)*hermitPolynomial(n-2,x);
}
```

How the function can be transformed to an iterative solution using stack? Also what are the basics of transforming a recursion to an iterative function using stack?

I managed to transform less difficult recursions(like Fibonacci) to an iterative stack solution.

This is the solution that I tried, but I didn't think of a way to keep track of "2*x" and "2*(n-1)":

```
int hermitPolynomialIter(int n, int x){
    std::stack<int> s;
    int result = 0;
    s.push(n);
    while(!s.empty()){
        int temp = s.top(); s.pop();
        if(temp == 1){
            result+=1;
        }
        else if(temp == 2){
            result+=2*x;
        }
        else{
            s.push(temp-1);
            s.push(temp-2);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to use a stack? The iterative solution is just a loop

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number mainly for practicing the usage of stacks. But also there are languages(like python) which have recursion depth limit and because of that iteration is better in some cases. Thank you!

Comment: part of practicing stacks is to learn when to use them and when not. You turn something relatively simple into something relatively complicated. Just saying. If all the purpose of this is to practice `std::stack` you should maybe mention that in the question

Comment: I gave it a try, but sorry, I really don't see how a stack fits in here. You seem to want to use the stack to keep track of the last two previous results but then the loop `while(!s.empty())` makes no sense. In each iteration you add the last two values back to the stack, hence it is never empty

Comment: well no, actually thats not what you store in the stack. I admit, I dont understand what you do store in the stack ;) Is it just a very convoluted loop counter?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I understand your point. Thank you!

Comment: I tried storing the Hermit polynomial index in the stack(worked for fibonacci), but I don't know if that is the correct approach for this.

Comment: the mathematican they are named after is called Charles Hermite. They are not hermit polynomials but Hermite Polynomials

Comment: well ok, your stack is indeed just a very complicated loop counter. Consider what the values are in the stack in each iteration. You get the same much simpler with a for loop and the stack does not really help with the actual calculation (other than storing the indices)

Comment: fwiw, the latest answer is using the stack as a (complicated) way to store the last two previous results, and thats what I was expecting to find in your code first. Thats a way to do it, but still my recommendation applies: Be aware that the only reason to use a stack here is to practice using a stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me notice that the [recurrence formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Recurrence_relation) is

```
H_n(x) = 2xH_{n-1}(x) - 2(n-1)H_{n-2}(x)
```

(notice the minus sign).

Here is a solution, together with a small test computing the first polynomials at x=1, and x=2.

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

int hermitePolynomial(int n, int x)
{
  std::stack<int> s;
  if (n == 0)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  else if (n == 1)
    {
      return 2 * x;
    }
  else
    {
      s.push(1);
      s.push(2 * x);
      for (int k = 2; k <= n; ++k)
    {
      auto hermite_k_minus_1 = s.top();
      s.pop();
      auto hermite_k_minus_2 = s.top();
      s.pop();
      auto hermite_k = 2 * x * hermite_k_minus_1 - 2 * (k - 1) * hermite_k_minus_2;
      s.push(hermite_k_minus_1);
      s.push(hermite_k);
    }
      return s.top();
    }
}

int main()
{
  for (const int x : { 1, 2 })
    {
      std::cout << "Polynomials at x = " << x << std::endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    std::cout << "H_" << i << "(" << x << ") = " << hermitePolynomial(i, x) << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

See it [Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d85a141a6853b6dd).

The main idea is that you iterate on a loop to compute the k-th polynomial, and you keep on the stack the 2 last polynomials, i.e., the polynomial for index k-1 and k-2.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Notice that the recursive formula expresses `Hn` in terms of two preceding evaluations (namely `Hn-1` and `Hn-2`). Hence you can perform it using just two variables that hold these evaluations (let `H1` and `H2`), and shift them when you increase `n`.

The body of the loop reads

```
H0= 2 * X * H1 + 2 * (N-1) * H2;
H2= H1;
H1= H0;
N++;
```

The following invariant will hold: `H1 = Hn-1 and H2 = Hn-2`, for all iterations.

I let you find out how the variables `H0`, `H1` and `H2` should be initialized (consider `N=2`).